# setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener causes statusBarColor change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-theme

In my activity, I have a custom color set for statusBar and navigationbar using

```
 <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/mainUIColor</item>
 <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/mainUIColor</item>
```

In this activity, I have a RecyclerView. And I want it to scroll to the bottom when the user opens the soft keyboard. The following snippet does that job,

```
View rootView = findViewById(R.id.chat_root_view).getRootView();
 ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(rootView, (v, insets) -> {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            return insets;
        });
```

But when this function is called, It’s also resetting the statusBar and navigationbar color which I set in my themes.xml. How can I scroll the recyclerView without changing the systemBar colors?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Not yet. I removed `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener`

Comment: Check out this answer I got on my question just now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75259470/1734802

Comment: @Peter Recently I added ```com.vanniktech:emoji``` EmojiKeyboard to my project. Now the ```setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener``` is not working for me.